# import javax.mail.session how?

Tags: java, smtp

I am trying to connect SMTP using java.
I have included mail.jar in my program but I am not able to import javamail.session.

plz give me some idea hw to get it .

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you put it to classpath after including in your program?

Comment: Provide more details what did you do, which IDE do you use, which error did you get: compile time or runtime, etc

Comment: it is a compile time error I write Session s = new Session.getInstance(para); but it shows error that session cant be resolved

Comment: Looks like you didn't specified all properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Included in my program" can be interpreted many ways. You need to have the mail jar on your [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) both when you compile the program and when you run it. Provide some more detail, error messages, etc., and we can give you a better answer.

Comment: I have imported javax.mail.*; it gives no error but when I want to have a session and write Session s = new Session(); it shows error that session cant be resolved

Comment: Right. Read up on the classpath, what it is, and what you have to do with it to be able to use third-party libraries. Try the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) to get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can not just create new Session... but rather you will need to:

```
Properties lProperties = ...// see pop3 properties - java help
Session lSession = Session.getInstance(lProperties);
Store lStore = lSession.getStore("pop3");
```

Besides that you might want to import one by one (rather then all classes) and that might point to the missing class, path, jar...

Comment: plus make sure that you have mail.jar and activation.jar